# React Router with many different URL variations

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a site. 
`http://example.com`

On my site I have multiple languages which get appended to the url.
So the homepage becomes something such as

`http://example.com/english`

When the user navigates to the account section, it is a React single page app with React Router
`http://example.com/english/account`

On this account section, there are multiple tabs that load different templates

`http://example.com/english/account/login`

`http://example.com/english/account/create-account`

Now the 'english' part of the url could be any language (french, german, spanish). How would I set up my React routing to account for this dynamic part of the url? I ultimately want to do something with a wildcard effect, but this doesn't seem to work

```
<NavLink className="nav" to="/*/account/login">
      <div> 
             <h5>Login</h5>
       </div>
</NavLink>
```

Adding explicit values such as
`/english/account/login` seems to work. But I'd rather not hardcode every language

Comment: You could have your Links set up like `/${locale}/account/login` (within backticks for string extrapolation) and your Route paths defined like `"/:locale/account/login"` and render a shared component while passing the locale as a prop (and insert locale-specific strings format dates/numbers etc. accordingly). Not sure if you want to handle separate templates for each locale or a shared one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use props.match.url for creating relative urls.

```
<NavLink className="nav" to={this.props.match.url}+"/account/login">
  <div> 
         <h5>Login</h5>
   </div>
</NavLink>
```